# jQuery. Showing div only if form boxes are checked

Tags: jquery, html

I need to have a div hidden at the start and then fade in once the two check boxes have been checked. Here is what I have so far (based on another question from here):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="terms" id="terms" />
<input type="checkbox" name="age" id="age" />

<div id="lists">
   <!-- my div content goes in here -->
</div>



  $("#lists").hide();

  $("#terms" && "#age").click(function(){
    $("#lists").fadeToggle();
  });
```

I can't get it to work. I can get it to work with one check box obviously but I need it only to fade in when both boxes are checked. I am still learning jQuery so forgive me if this is a simple solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use something like that :

```
$("#terms, #age").change(function(){
    var checked = $("#terms").prop('checked') && $("#age").prop('checked');
    $("#lists")[checked ? 'fadeIn' : 'fadeOut']();
});
```

Comment: +1, good solution. Answers the question and handles if checkbox(es) are unchecked.

Comment: boom! That worked. And I learned something. Thank you everyone for the help.

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="terms" id="terms" class="mycheck"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="age" id="age" class="mycheck"/>

<div id="lists">
 <!-- my div content goes in here -->
</div>



$("#lists").hide();

$(".mycheck").on("change",function(){
   if($("#terms").prop('checked') && $("#age").prop('checked')){
       $("#lists").show();
     } 
 });
```

Comment: If you are going to use show, let me suggest you something : `$("#lists").toggle($("#terms").prop('checked') && $("#age").prop('checked'));`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know jquery doesn't offer multiple selectors using &&. They currently do multiple selectors by separating selectors with a comma. You can see how this is done with the [Jquery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/). Another thing to notice is that even if you correct that for the code you have provided, you will see the expected behavior when you click on one checkbox, but if you click on the other it will hide the #lists div element.